# Building Visual Studio solution using devenv command line

Tags: c++, qt, build, devenv

I am trying to build, using **devenv**, a Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 C++ solution which compiles and builds properly using the IDE, version 15.9.12. So far, so good.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/project-devenv-exe?view=vs-2019

When trying to build using *Windows command line and devenv command*, I find problems with the includes, I don't know how to tell the system where to look. I have appended **in the Windows PATH** all the folders where the needed HEADERS are, however it does not work.

Any ideas? What am I doing wrong?.

Thank you.

Comment: Use msbuild instead. Also, Windows folder has nothing to do with the SDK headers. they are not there.

Comment: What if you run in Visual Studio command prompt? Does it work then?

Comment: Indeed I am running win32-msvc Qt.5.12 command prompt. My project is Qt based.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis Using MSBuild instead is giving back exactly the same errors. Thanks anyway.

Comment: If the project builds from VS, it should build with msbuild since VS uses msbuild itself. If it's a QT issue then - good luck (I 've added a tag).

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis It is not a Qt issue. The issue looks like:  c:\terrasystest\terratronnewinterface\t_configuration.hpp(5): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'T_DBTarget.hpp': No such file or directory. That is not happening in Visual Studio, I assume that besides MSBuild there will more things used in the IDE.

Comment: If you are building the same .sln file then it should work.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis I found out what was going out. I was running a command line as an administrator, like I always do. An admin account does not see/recognize other drives, at least with the configuration we have here.